# download file from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm setting up some html exporting to excel and is doing this via jquery $.post. The result is data

```
$.post('/exportToExcel.php', function(data) {    
    // data is the file i want to download now... how to trigger it?
});
```

data is the returned value (the file) from the server, simply doing alert(data) will output a bigger window full of lol. how to i trigger so the file is able to be download?

Comment: Just for the record, is this file stored at any point ? Are you trying to return the actual file in `data` or its relative path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that using Ajax. Load the file in an iframe, and send this HTTP header with the file:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

Comment: cant't i just set src of a iframe to the data and reload the iframe?

Comment: How do you set the src to data? You set it to an URL.